# Not able to retrieve image in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, image, gridview, 3-tier

//This is the code of presentation layer

```
    BusinessAccessLayer.BLogic obj1 = new BusinessAccessLayer.BLogic();
string i = DDMenu.SelectedValue;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt=obj1.getBind(i);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

//This is the code of business access layer

```
 DataAccessLayer.DBLogic obj1 = new DataAccessLayer.DBLogic();
 public DataTable getBind(string i)
        {


            return obj1.getInstrument(i);

        }
```

//This is the code of database access layer

```
public DataTable getInstrument(string i)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

            try
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectedval", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", i);

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;


            }

            catch
            {

                throw;

            }

            finally
            {

                con.Close();

            }

        }
```

Here I have inserted some images in sql server by insert query. But while binding the data to gridview I am not able to see those images in gridview.

Comment: You need to use the BinaryWrite method to display images in the app, No matter if it is a gridview or not.

Comment: @Kami... ohhh how to do that? I am not getting it

Comment: You retrieve the image from your SQL db into a byte[] variable, e.g. byte[] img = dbColumn. Convert your image column in the GridView to a template column and in the OnRowDataBinding method use Response.BinaryWrite method for the image.

Comment: @Kami... Can you send it into code format?

Comment: Look at this. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: It is much easier to have the images stored in a folder on the web server and store the links in the DB rather that storing all images in the DB. That way the load time is faster and you are putting less load on the DB server.